# Unable to delete file via Bash

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt, xdt

I have created a file via the kudu bash terminal called 'applicationHost.xdt'. This is part of the app service plan hosted by Microsoft Azure. For some reason, upon creation, the file was indented with a single space prefix in the directory.  I need to delete this file, but am unable to get the terminal to see it. See below for some attempts at trying to figure it out:

[image]

Comment: Try *rm* space and then press the TAB  key. It will list out all the files in the folder and loop through them one by one or display the list of files if multiple files exists and bash cannot detemine which to choose. Or, `rm *.xdt -f` will work too. 

Note: A better practice is to use underscore as prefix, however, feel free to choose any acceptable prefixes you like including $, _, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! The shell didn't have autocomplete enabled, but 'rm *.xdt -f' worked nicely.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped, would you please mark it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *rm* space and then press the TAB key. It will list out all the files in the folder and loop through them one by one or display the list of files if multiple files exists and bash cannot detemine which to choose.

Or, `rm *.xdt -f` will work too.

**Note:** A better practice is to use underscore as prefix, however, feel free to choose any acceptable prefixes you like including `$`, `_`, etc.